# what is 'this' really represent in emberJS framework?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm really new in emberJS,I see many 'this.' in the official Guides .
In ember Object model I know 'this.' represent the object itself,such as follow:

```
 var obj = Ember.Object.extend({
  baz: {
    foo: 'BLAMMO',
    bar: 'BLAZORZ'
  },

  something: Ember.computed('baz.{foo,bar}', function() {
    return this.get('baz.foo') + ' ' + this.get('baz.bar');
  })
});
```

this means obj itself,but in other case,such as models like follow:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    this.store.push({
      data: [{
        id: 1,
        type: 'album',
        attributes: {
          title: 'Fewer Moving Parts',
          artist: 'David Bazan',
          songCount: 10
        },
        relationships: {}
      }, {
        id: 2,
        type: 'album',
        attributes: {
          title: 'Calgary b/w I Can\'t Make You Love Me/Nick Of Time',
          artist: 'Bon Iver',
          songCount: 2
        },
        relationships: {}
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

what is 'this' really represent?

Answer (score 2):

`this` is totally dependant on where and what and how a function was called or object created. The value of `this` is a construct of javascript itself and not ember. I would strongly encourage you to read more about `this` in javascript. Its really fundamental to becoming a good javascript developer.

Here's some good resources that helped me:

- [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)
- http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

As for the code in your original question, the vast majority of objects in Ember extend the base ember object, and `Route` is no exception. So in the lower block of code, `this` is referring to the route object that the `model()` function is defined in.

Comment: Although you should probably mention that `this` in an action refers to the object that contains the `actions` hash, not the `actions` hash itself as one would normally expect with default JS behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ember tries to always give a a this that is the current object in almost all cases. In actions its the normal object as well, same for computed properties, observers and so on.

I think the only totally different thing is the router DSL.

So in both your example `this` is the current object. In the second you are just able to call `this.store` because the store is injected into the route.

Comment: your idea is correct,I have read many articles and finally I find 'this' in javascript is quite different from java.'this' is passed as param of  the function,so it depends on the context of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Like xcskier mentioned, this depends on the context in which you are in. Why don't you examine your "this" yourself by doing something like

```
console.log(this);
```